# Icon color remains blue on IOS toolbar xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have used a **red icon** on a `Toolbar` , but it still remains in color blue it's like by default. How can i change it to color red.
because initially the icon's color is originally red. 
How can i tackle this please.

**Below is the image :**

[image]

**and this is Xaml Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    Icon ="nav_icon.png"    Title="Ea "

    x:Class="EAMobileDirectory.MasterPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Image   Source="featured_newline_1.png"  Margin="0,1,0,0"/>
        <ListView x:Name="listView"   Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SeparatorVisibility="None">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**I have also Changed My AppDelegate.cs File According @Steven  below is my code i changed:**

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App());
            UIToolbar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
            UIToolbar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Green;

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to the `TintColor` property taking over on iOS. It enables you to provide images in every color you want and using `TintColor` you can color them in any color. To change this try adding this lines in your `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

This will style the icons for each UINavigationBar in the app.

Comment: the icon didn't change ,  but is that the toolbar which has the Title because  when i add <Content.Toolbar/> in xaml , another layer is added on top of the one which is visible which i don't want . Are there other ways.

Comment: Is `featured_newline_1.png` the icon turning blue or `nav_icon.png`? In case of the last you need to change UIToolbar in my sample to `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: it's `nav_icon.png` changinging the color , check out my post , i have edited it again

Comment: Try changing `UIToolbar` to `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: it has worked like charm , update your answer and i vote it thanks man.